# How can I select only the immediate parent node of a text string using xpath

Tags: xpath

Given the following html:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <div>
   <p>During the interim there shall be nourishment supplied</p>
  </div>
  <div>
   <a href="/interim">In the interim</a>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

and the following xpath:

```
//*[contains(.,'interim')]
```

The elements returned by this include the HTML tag, the BODY tag, etc. So every ancestor parent is returned.

I only want the immediate container nodes, i.e. the P and the A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
//*[contains(text(),'interim')]
```

i.e. replace `.` with `text()`

This will check all elements that have a text node child that contains the text `interim`.

The difference being that `.`, when used with a string related function, returns the entire text content of the element, which is why it returns every ancestor.

Comment: However this only returns the A element if the html is like so: `<html>
 <body>
  <div>
   <p>During the interim there shall be nourishment supplied</p>
  </div>
  <div>
   <a href="/interim">In the interim</a> there will be an interim again
  </div>
 </body>
</html>` 

Ideally, it should in this case return A and DIV

Comment: I've asked this as a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39043885/how-can-i-select-only-the-immediate-parent-node-of-a-text-string-using-xpath-for